# How to get Client ID in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to know how to get Client ID in Stripe ? On new view, I feel hard to find Client ID.

Some instruction says that I need go to Connect panel.

But, when in Connect page, I can't get the Client ID.
[image]

Comment: It's on https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/connect . But note you only need that if using OAuth, and there are limited reasons to use OAuth with Stripe Connect at the moment(it's really only for if you are building a read-only extension to connect to existing Stripe accounts, all other use cases should use the Accounts API).

Comment: hi, @karllekko . thank you for the answer, now I can see Client ID. can you make your answer as answer not a comment. So, I can mark your answer as correct

Comment: is there a way to get the client_id via API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to login on Stripe and navigate to this link: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/connect

Answer (score 3):

You can find your client_id here in docs: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#using-oauth
Keep in mind that you should be logged in so your client_id would be displayed directly in the documentation